indexing is not working properly after upgrade mysql 8.0.28
The issue is coming after up gradation of mysql 8.0.28. I have a table called user_products. When I run the EXPLAIN SELECT query on it, the possible keys identified are user_id, productId, status, product_to, and product_multicol. The key is productId, with a key length of 4.
upgrade mysql from 5.7 to 8.0.28
The query itself is:
    SELECT user_products.id,user_products.status,user_products.delivery_date,user_products.product_to,user_products.category_id,users.username,user_groups.name FROM user_products 
LEFT JOIN category ON category.id = user_products.category_id
LEFT JOIN users ON user_products.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN user_groups ON user_groups.id = users.user_group_id
WHERE user_products.status = 0 AND user_products.product_to = "10" AND user_products.delivery_date <= CURDATE() 
ORDER BY user_products.id DESC

For user_products.product_to = "49", the query takes approximately 5 seconds to execute. However, for other values of product_to, it only takes 0.007 seconds.
When I tried with FORCE INDEX it's taking less time.

upgrade to or from what version?  if you mean upgrade to 8.0.28, why not 8.0.39?  do you know what the query plan was before the upgrade?  please do edit your question to show (as text, not images) the explain output and show create table ... for all relevant tables

Everyone using MySQL should read this: https://www.percona.com/blog/do-not-upgrade-to-any-version-of-mysql-after-8-0-37/

Add this index:
user_products:  INDEX(status, product_to, delivery_date)

If that does not help, please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN SELECT.
Also, tell us about the distribution of product_to.  It sounds like there are a lot of 49's
